# What is the origin of the phrase "Kennst du Wayne?!"

Tags: etymology

It is used as the annoying version of "who cares".
I hear this phrase from time to time and wondered about the etymology of it.

What is the origin of the phrase "Kennst du Wayne?"

Comment: Wayne interessiert's?

Comment: http://mahopa.de/bilder/lustige-forenbilder/hey-mich-interessierts.jpg

Comment: Ich meine mich zu erinnern, in irgendeiner Sprache ein Wort entdeckt zu haben, das ca. "egal" heißt und natürlich wie *Wayne* klingt. Das müsste türkisch, arabisch oder irgendwas gewesen sein, damit es in die Jugendsprache übergehen kann. Da das sowieso wayne ist, bleibt es bei einer Randnotiz.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eigentlich hatte ich das nur als Kommentar gedacht. Aber möglicherweise ist die mir eigentlich eher bekannte Phrase

> Wayne interessiert's?

auch die Ursache des Worts: Etwas verändert von

> Wen interessiert's?

[Stupidedia](http://www.stupidedia.org/stupi/Wayne) hat einen Artikel dazu, aus dem man auch diverse verwandte Phrasen entnehmen kann. Allerdings ist das eher satirisch geschrieben - man sollte vieles daher nicht wörtlich nehmen, sondern eher annehmen, dass es sich auch um verwandte Phrasen handelt, wenn einem etwas spanisch vorkommt :)

> Kennst du Wayne?

ist dann eher eine logische Konsequenz aus der bereits existierenden Phrase. "Kennst du X?" ist eine Frage, mit der man auch ein Gespräch über X einleiten kann, oder jemanden an X erinnert. Unter jungen Leuten ersetzt man häufig ganze Phrasen damit, wie in diesem Beispiel. Aus "Wayne interessiert's" wird daher "Kennst du Wayne".

Comment: +1, Stupipedia als Quelle

Comment: Jedenfalls umfangreichere Quelle als Wiki: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computerspieler-Jargon#W -- ich glaub das kommt einfach aus der Bestrebung, Wörter irgendwie "cooler" zu schreiben. Ich sag nur 1337... ^^

Comment: "Wayne" hat jedenfalls ein ziemliches Eigenleben bekommen, inkl. der Referenzen auf John Wayne. siehe z.B. http://forum.ikariam-tools.com/images/smilies/wayne.png oder http://www.ariva.de/wayne_a315558. :)

Comment: @musiKk: Hoppla. Korrigiert. Stupipedia klingt aber irgendwie besser^^

Comment: Tolle Antwort: Ich habe nur das starke Gefühl, es handelt sich um eine John Wayne-Ableitung und das sollte auch drinnen stehen :)

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: Eine gewisse Verwandschaft des Namens ist nicht zu leugnen, vermutlich kommt daher die Idee. Aber wahrscheinlich hat es mit John Wayne selbst nicht viel zu tun, oder doch? :)

Comment: Würde schon sagen: John Wayne ist ein absolutes Beispiel dafür wie egal einem etwas sein kann: "Ist mir Wayne", und "Wayne interessiert" sagen genau das selbe aus. Eben diese Stoik :)

Comment: @SamuelHerzog: Nein. John Wayne ist nur zufällig jemand diesen Namens. Da Wayne nicht so geläufig ist wie "Smith" ist die Prominenz aber wohl Vorraussetzung, dass der Spruch überhaupt funktioniert. Hieße John Wayne James Dean und umgekehrt, dann hieße der Spruch dennoch "Wayne interessierts" und würde genauso funktionieren.

Answer (score 6):

Ich kenne das ganze Gebilde als scherzhaft gebrauchte rhetorische Frage. Wenn jemand etwas Langweiliges erzählt, fragt das Gegenüber:

"Kennst du Wayne?"
"Nein?!"
"Wayne Interessierts?"

"Wayne Interessierts" ist damit der Vor- und Nachname einer fiktiven Person, wobei der tatsächlich existierende Vorname "Wayne" phonetisch dem Fragewort "wen" ähnelt. Der erfundene Nachname "Interessierts", der ja erst in der darauffolgenden Antwort genannt wird, dient dann als Pointe, sodass die ursprünglich beabsichtigte (ernst gemeinte) Frage "Wen interessierts?" mit ironischem Unterton geäußert werden kann.

Comment: Es gibt auch einen ziemlich kultigen (vermutlich 80er-Jahre) Film, dessen Name ich leider vergessen habe, in dem ein gewisser Wayne eine Radiosendung "Wayne interessiert's!" hat. Leider ist es sehr schwer, danach zu googlen, weil nur irgendwelche unsinnigen Foreneinträge dabei herauskommen.

Comment: @fifaltra Du meinst "Wayne's World". https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne’s_World Es ist allerdings unwahrscheinlich, dass ein amerikanischer Musikfilm was damit zu tun hat.

Answer (score -4):

Dieser Ausspruch wurde im Jahr 1988 von Mario Deida erfunden. Mario hat häufig Kalauer und Wortspiele gebracht. Witzigerweise kennen nur sehr wenige Leute diesen Ursprung des Satzes, wobei nahezu jeder den Satz kennt.
Die Behauptung, dieser Ausspruch sei erst mit der Internetära entstanden ist daher definitiv falsch.

Comment: Willkommen auf "German Language and Usage". Hast du irgendwelche Quellen für diese Aussage? Eine Google-Suche nach "Mario Deida" führt mich leider zu keinen nennenswerten Ergebnissen.

Comment: Ich finde noch nicht einmal einen Treffer der mir erklärt wer "Mario Deida" ist oder war. Ein Komiker? Vielleicht kannst du ja auch einen Tip geben, in welche Richtung man weiter nach einer Quelle suchen kann.