# Is "falls du wen kennst" right?

Tags: grammar

I saw *wen* in a sentence, where I expected *jemanden.*

> Ich möchte zum 31.10 ausziehen. Falls ihr **wen** kennt, der eine Wohnung sucht, meldet euch.

Is this right?

Comment: Not to be confused with [What is the origin of the phrase “Kennst du Wayne?!”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1493/9551)

Comment: Ich kenne nur **dem** Vermieter seinen Bruder... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is non-standard spoken German.

> Falls ihr jemanden kennt, der eine Wohnung sucht, meldet euch.

would be correct.

Comment: @c.p.: Certainly, people do speak and write like that; more likely when making a short note for friends or the neighbours, less likely when holding a formal speech in a university context.

Answer (score 5):

It is right, but a colloquialism. In written standard language, you would indeed prefer *(irgend)jemand* as the indefinite pronoun over *(irgend)wer*.

Comment: I wonder what the regional distribution of this is.

Comment: And I wonder the regional distribution of »Ich möchte **zum** 31.10 ausziehen«. I would say: »Ich möchte **am** 31.10 ausziehen«

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Das heißt aber was anderes. _Am 31. 10._ würde bedeuten, das ist der Tag, an dem die Möbel bewegt werden und er/sie die Schlüssel abgibt. _Zum 31. 10._ bezieht sich auf den Kündigungstermin, aber vielleicht zieht er/sie schon Tage vorher aus.

Comment: @chirlu: Siehe: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25298/möchte-zum-31-10-ausziehen