# möchte zum 31.10. ausziehen

Tags: grammar, meaning, regional

In einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25288/is-falls-du-wen-kennst-right) las ich diesen Satz:

> Ich möchte zum 31. 10. ausziehen.

Ich habe diese Formulierung zwar schon des öfteren gehört, hielt sie bisher aber immer für falsch. Ich würde den Satz auf eine von diesen beiden Arten formulieren:

> a. Ich möchte **bis zum** 31. 10. ausziehen.
>   b. Ich möchte **am** 31. 10. ausziehen.

Die beiden Varianten haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen:

**a:** Ich will irgendwann zwischen jetzt und dem 31. 10. die Wohnung verlassen. Ich habe also vor, spätestens ab dem 1. 11. nicht mehr dort zu wohnen. Das kann möglicherweise aber auch schon früher (z.B. schon am 8. 10.) der Fall sein.

**b:** Ich will genau am 31.10. ausziehen. Keinen Tag früher und keinen Tag später.

Bei der Formulierung »Ich möchte zum 31. 10. ausziehen« ist mir nicht klar, ob damit **a** oder **b** gemeint ist. (Ich persönlich würde eher auf **b** tippen, bin mir aber unsicher.)

Meine Fragen:

1. Ist »Ich möchte zum 31. 10. ausziehen« korrektes Deutsch?
2. Was genau ist damit gemeint?
3. Gibt es regionale Unterschiede in der Beantwortung der Fragen 1 und 2?

---

**Nachtrag:**

Weil es hier bei einer Antwort ein Missverständnis gab, möchte ich noch einmal ausdrücklich klarstellen, dass es hier um

> **Ausziehen** zum 31.10.

geht. Es geht in dieser Frage **nicht** um

> <del>**Kündigen** zum 31.10.</del>

Letzterer Terminus ist klar: Wenn man »zum 31.10.« kündigt, gilt der Vertrag bis einschließlich dem 31.10. und ist ab einschließlich dem 1.11. nicht mehr gültig bzw. bindend. Daraus lässt sich aber leider nicht schließen, was mit »zum 31.10. **ausziehen**« gemeint ist, denn auch wenn auch klar ist, dass die Gültigkeit eines Vertrages genau **an** einem bestimmten Tag endet, ist damit nicht klar, ob man auch genau an diesem Tag auszieht, oder irgendwann davor.

Comment: 1 -> Wahrscheinlich Umgangssprache halt // 2 -> Es ist a gemeint // 3 -> Wenn, dann wahrscheinlich entlang der Main-Linie.

Comment: @Em1 ad 1) eher Richtung Juristendeutsch würde ich sagen. Schließlich kündigt man Verträge "zu" einem Enddatum. ad 2) etwas unhiflreich. ad 3) nur eine Vermutung, oder? außerdem... ist das eine Antwort

Comment: Imho kann Frage 1 nur schwer beantwortet werden. Ich hab an der Formulierung nichts auszusetzen, aber ob man mir es in einem Fachaufsatz ankreiden würde?! I don't know. – Regionale Unterschiede lassen sich jetzt wahrscheinlich schlecht beantwortet. Man müsste eine CW-Antwort erstellen, wo jeder editiert, wo er wohnt, wie er es kennt, und dann wissen wir es iwann.

Comment: @Vogel612 Nein, keine Antwort. Die einzige Antwort (im Sinne einer Antwort), die ich geben kann ist: "Es ist a gemeint". Auch wenn du es unhilfreich definierst, es ist *die* Antwort. — Wobei ich das Gefühl habe, dass du Frage 1 beantwortet hast. Wenn das Juristendeutsch ist, ist es richtiges Deutsch.

Comment: Der Kontext der ursprünglichen Frage war übrigens ein bloßer Facebook-Beitrag, der allem Anschein nach auf die Schnelle geschrieben wurde.

Comment: Aus dem ursprünglichen Kontext: Es sollte wohl gesagt werden, dass die Wohnung ab 1. 11. frei ist, es wurden keine Umzugshelfer gesucht, also war (a) zumindest gemeint.

Comment: @CarstenS: Auch wenn ich vorhabe, nicht *bis zum* sondern *genau am* 31.10. auszuziehen, wird die Wohnung ab dem 1.11. frei sein. Deine Argumentation liefert also keine Entscheidungshilfe zwischen a und b. Es kann schon sein, dass tatsächlich a gemeint ist, aber diesen Schluss kann man aus deinem Argument nicht ziehen, weil dein Argument auch mit der anderen Deutung (am 31.10.) kompatibel ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, die für den Leser wesentliche Information ist die aus (a). Es ist natürlich möglich, dass er ausdrücken wollte, dass er im Dezember auszieht, das wissen wir nicht.

Comment: @CarstenS: Wieso Dezember? Ich kann dir nicht ganz folgen. Ich habe das Gefühl, wir reden von verschiedenen Dingen. Antwort **a** (*Ausziehen bis zum 31.10.*) heißt: *Ausziehen entweder heute (am 31.8.) oder morgen (am 1.9.) oder am 2.9. oder ... usw. ... oder am 30.10. oder am 31.10*. Also irgendwann zwischen heute und dem 31.10. Antwort **b** heißt: *Ausziehen ganz genau am 31.10.*, also an keinem anderen Tag. In beiden Fällen ist die Wohnung ab dem 1.11. frei (in Fall **a** sogar schon irgendwann davor), und in beiden Fällen findet im Dezember kein Auszug statt.

Comment: Noch einmal: Die wesentliche Information im Kontext ist (a). Dies ist, wie ich in meiner Antwort geschrieben habe, auch was "zum" ausdrückt. Es ist daher plausibel, dass das auch ausgedrückt werden sollte. Natürlich ist möglich, dass der Schreiber das stärkere (b) ausdrücken wollte und sich schlecht ausgedrückt hat. Oder dass er etwas ganz anderes meinte.

Comment: @CarstenS: Die wesentliche Information im Kontext ist nicht (a) (»irgendwann zwischen heute und dem 31.10.«). Die wesentliche Information ist: »Ab dem 1.11. ist die Wohnung mit Sicherheit frei«. Und diese wesentliche Information folgt sowohl aus (a) als auch aus (b). Es ist auch durchaus richtig, dass (a) einigermaßen plausibel ist, aber (b) ist genau gleich plausibel. Es kann auch durchaus sein, dass mit »zum« (ohne »bis«) »bis zum« gemeint ist. Aber deine Argumentation ist leider nicht geeignet, die andere Möglichkeit auszuschließen oder auch nur weniger plausibel erscheinen zu lassen.

Comment: Ich habe nicht argumentiert, dass es so sein müsse, beantwortet habe ich die Frage in meiner Antwort. Ich habe nur bemerkt, dass das im Kontext auch sehr gut passt.

Comment: »Weil es hier bei einer Antwort missverständnisse gab« … Nein, du hast die Antwort falsch verstanden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ist »Ich möchte zum 31. 10. ausziehen« korrektes Deutsch?**

Von Satzbau und Grammatik her ist alles in Ordnung. Darüber hinaus ist es eher eine Frage von üblich / idiomatisch / verständlich als von korrekt oder inkorrekt. Ich finde aber auch da nichts gravierend auffälliges. Es klingt halt etwas formal.

**Was genau ist damit gemeint?**

Der gemeinsame Nenner aller Kontruktionen nach dem Muster "zum [Datum] [Verb]" ist meiner Meinung nach der Fokus darauf, wann der Effekt einer Handlung relevant wird:

> Wir suchen einen neuen Mitarbeiter zum 1. Januar. (Wir suchen bestimmt schon eine Weile vorher - Hauptsache, er fängt am 1. Januar an.)
>
> Hiermit kündige ich meinen Mietvertrag zum 30. September.
>
> Die neue Version der Software wird zum 1. Juni in Produktion gehen. (Möglicherweise wird sie auch am 1. Juni installiert, vielleicht auch schon am Abend des 30. Mai oder mit noch längerem Vorlauf - egal: am 1. Juni steht sie zur Verfügung.)

Von daher würde ich Deinen Satz im Sinne von "bis zum" verstehen. Es geht darum, bis wann der Auszug spätestens endgültig abgeschlossen ist, nicht wann er tatsächlich stattfindet. Möglicherweise hängt es auch vom Kontext ab. Aber zumindest kann ich mir nicht vorstellen, dass jemand einen Unterschied in Bezug auf den konkreten Auszugstermin sieht zwischen

> Unser Vermieter hat uns gekündigt. Wir müssen zum 31. Oktober ausziehen.

und

> Wir müssen ausziehen. Unser Vermieter hat uns zum 31. Oktober gekündigt.

Auch wenn Du explizit nach *ausziehen* gefragt hast und nicht nach *kündigen*: ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass der Gebrauch hier vom einen auf das andere Verb übergegangen ist.

**Gibt es regionale Unterschiede in der Beantwortung der Fragen 1 und 2?**

Wie gesagt, ich glaube eher, dass der Kontext einen Unterschied machen könnte. Und auch, dass es eher nach einer formalen Ausdrucksweise klingt, macht für mich regionale Unterschiede weniger wahrscheinlich. Ganz ausschließen will ich sie aber nicht, schon allein, weil es sie auf jeden Fall in einem anderen Fall mit *zu* und *an* gibt: Ich bin in Sachsen aufgewachsen, und dort freuten wir uns auf Schnee *zu* Weihnachten (und auf den Weihnachtsmann). Jetzt wohne ich in Bayern, und hier sagt man "*an* Weihnachten". (Und die Geschenke bringt angeblich das Christkind, was für mich fast schon blasphemisch klingt.)

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese wirklich gute Antwort!

Comment: Ja, sehr gute Antwort. Am wahrscheinlichsten scheint mir übrigens die Deutung als Verkürzung von "bis zum 31. ausziehen", unterstützt durch den Anklang an "zum 31. kündigen", wo das *bis* nicht nur weggelassen werden kann, sondern sogar fehl am Platz wäre. So gesehen eine fast zwangsläufige Entwicklung.

Answer (score 3):

Die Formulierung mit "zum" ist üblich, wenn es um Termine geht, die eingehalten werden sollen, es ist also (a) gemeint.

Comment: Dass eine Formulierung üblich ist, weiß ich. Ich habe in der Frage ja bereits erwähnt, dass ich sie schon mehrfach gehört habe. Ich wollte wissen, ob sie korrekt ist (gemäß den Regeln, die man im Deutschunterricht lehrt). Dazu ein Beispiel:  »Der Lisa ihr Auto ist rot« (statt »Lisas Auto ist rot«) ist in weiten Teilen des deutschen Sprachraums üblich (u.a. dort wo ich wohne), aber dennoch kein korrektes Deutsch.

Comment: Du hast geschrieben, dass Dir nicht klar ist, ob (a) oder (b) gemeint ist, ich habe das beantwortet.

Comment: Auch wenn ich genau **am** 31.10. ausziehe, halte ich den Termin ein. Es könnte also genauso gut auch **b** gemeint sein.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Auch, wenn das im Kontext (für den Vertragspartner) meistens egal ist, kann man bei der Aussage, dass der "Auszug am 31.10." stattfindet, davon ausgehen, dass man die Person am 30.10. noch vor Ort antrifft, und dass im Lauf des 31.10. Möbel geräumt werden. Das sehe ich in der Formulierung "zum 31.10." nicht in dieser Form garantiert. Es ist richtig, dass in beiden Fällen der Termin eingehalten wird, aber es wird bei "zu" eher keine Aussage darüber gemacht, was vorher passiert. Allerdings sollte man auch andere Vertragsarten betrachten, bei denen diese ...

Comment: ... Interpretation möglicherweise nicht unbedingt konsequent durchgehalten wird. Ein Arbeitsbeginn oder ein Einzug zum 01.11. findet beispielsweise wirklich erst an dem Tag statt.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Auch nicht unbedingt. Es ist üblich, Leute zum Monatsersten einzustellen, auch wenn der auf einen arbeitsfreien Tag fällt (Wochenende); umgekehrt werden vor dem offiziellen Ende der Tätigkeit oft noch Überstunden abgefeiert und Resturlaub verbraucht.

Comment: @chirlu: Dann ist der *formale* Arbeitsbeginn dennoch an dem arbeitsfreien Tag. Ab genau jenem Tag (jedoch nicht vorher), auch wenn das ein Sonn- oder ein Feiertag ist, ist die Person Mitarbeiter des Unternehmens.

Comment: Wenn man jemanden zum Ersten einstellt, dann wird der Vertrag bereits vorher geschlossen, die Hauptwirkung entfaltet er ab dem Ersten. Passt doch.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Richtig. »*Ausziehen **am** 31.10.*« heißt »*Ich bin am 30.10. sicher noch da.*« Auch klar dürfte sein: »*Ausziehen **bis zum** 31.10.*« heißt »*Es ist unklar, ob ich am 30.10. noch da sein werde.*«. Beides heißt aber definitiv: »*Am 1.11. bin ich ganz sicher nicht mehr da.*« Carsten leitet aber aus der Einhaltung des Termins (also aus »*Am 1.11. bin ich ganz sicher nicht mehr da.*«) ab, dass damit nur eine der beiden Möglichkeiten gemeint sein kann, und dieser Schluss ist nach dem Gesetzten der Logik einfach nicht zulässig.

Comment: Der erste Teil der Antwort (»*das ist üblich*«) beantwortet nicht, ob das korrektes Deutsch ist. Der zweite Teil der Antwort enthält als Begründung einen unlogischen Schluss. Lediglich die Aussage, dass »a« gemeint ist, ist eine Antwort.

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin nicht begabt genug um ein entsprechendes Ngram heraufzuzaubern (das müsste dann eine Datumsvariable zwischen *zum* und dem Verb enthalten; daran bin ich gescheitert) aber eine Suche in Googlebüchern liefert das eine oder andere erhellende Resultat.

Ich habe nach *"zum 31." kündigen* (Anführungszeichen beachten) gesucht (denn die Suchanfrage nach *"zum 31." ausziehen* hat nichts gebracht; und ich war mir sicher, dass ich in der Nähe des einen Ausdrucks auch den anderen finden würde), und bin dabei unter anderem auf examenrelevantes Zivilrecht gestoßen – was mich nicht verwundert hat, denn ich halte die Formulierung *zu einem Zeitpunkt ausziehen* für etwas juristisch klingend. Das gegebene Beispiel behandelt eine Kündigung, die *zum 30. November* zugestellt werden muss, damit der Vertrag *zum 31. Dezember* aufgelöst wird. Der Mieter des Lagerplatzes hat den Platz laut Quelle ***zum 31. Dezember* geräumt**.

Es ging aus dem Text *nicht eindeutig* hervor, ob dieser Mieter am 31. alles weggeräumt hat, oder ob er schon am 20. Dezember kein Zeug mehr am Lagerplatz gelagert hat. Hätte er aber den Platz *am* 31. Dezember geräumt, würde ich das ausdrücken als »hat den Platz *am 31. Dezember* geräumt«.

Dieses Fundstück ist zwar anekdotisch, deckt sich aber mit meinem Sprachverständnis und meinem Sprachgebrauch. Und demnach wäre es auch sehr schwierig, Fundstücke in Büchern zu finden, denn zu einem Datum kündigt man in der Regel per Brief und man zieht zu einem Datum entweder mündlich oder per Schwarzbrettaushang/Gruppen-E-Mail aus.

Die direkten Antworten auf die Fragen:

1. Ja, denn was in einem Juristenhandbuch steht, ist in aller Regel korrektes (das heißt nicht unbedingt schönes!) Deutsch.
2. Damit ist die Bedeutung a) gemeint, es wird also so ausgezogen, dass die Wohnung am 31. Oktober leer ist, und der Nachmieter am 1. November seine Möbel reinstellen kann/der Vermieter am 1. November die Abrissbirne schwingen kann. Ob das am 31. Oktober, 30. Oktober oder 1. Oktober mehrheitlich geschieht, wie lange man braucht oder wie lange die Wohnung hernach leer steht, ist irrelevant.
3. Ich weiß nicht, inwiefern die Schweiz und Österreich die gleichen Formulierungen im gleichen Kontext verwenden.

Comment: Danke für 1. Du bist der erste, der diesen Teil beantwortet hat. Ad 2: Ich glaube nun auch, dass offenbar mehrheitlich a) verstanden wird. Aber Du lieferst leider genau dieselbe unlogische Argumentation wie Carsten. Denn auch wenn man genau **am** (also nicht *bis zum*) 31. 10. auszieht, ist die Wohnung am 31.10. leer (zumindest am Abend), und der Nachmieter kann am 1. 11. seine Möbel reinstellen bzw. der Eigentümer kann das Objekt am 1.11. abreißen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Zu 2. liefere ich gar keine Argumentation, nur einen (möglicherweise misslungenen) Präzisierungsversuch. *Warum* ich das so verstehe, kann ich dir tatsächlich nicht beantworten, nur *dass* ich das so verstehe.

Comment: Leider hast du auch nicht die gestellte Frage beantwortet. Gefragt habe ich nach ***ausziehen** zum 31.10.* Was ***kündigen** zum 31.10.* bedeutet, war wir klar und war nicht gefragt. Wenn man *zu* einem bestimmten Datum kündigt, ist der genannte Tag der letzte an dem der Vertrag noch gilt. Das sagt aber nichts darüber aus, ob man *genau an* diesem Tag auch auszieht, oder ob man *bis zu* diesem Tag auszieht. Es ist ja durchaus juristisch erlaubt, dass man bereits z.B. **am** 17. 10. auszieht, wenn man **zum** 31. 10. gekündigt hat.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ja, aber ich habe auch drinnenstehen, dass der Mieter in dem gefundenen Beispiel einen Lagerplatz *zum 31. Dezember geräumt* hat. Ob leerräumen oder ausziehen … halte ich für ausreichend synonymisch.

Comment: Auf genau diesen Satz wollte ich auch noch genauer eingehen: Du erklärst zwar ausführlich, was mit »*kündigen zum 31.10.*« gemeint ist, und schreibst dann, dass daraus zu schließen ist, dass der Mieter den Lagerplatz **zum** 31.10. geräumt hat. - Leider ohne zu erklären, was genau damit gemeint ist, denn genau das will ich ja wissen. Heißt das, dass er den Lagerplatz genau am 31.10. räumt, oder das er ihn *bis zum* 31.10. räumt?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich erkläre überhaupt nicht, was mit »kündigen zum Termin *x*« gemeint ist. Ich verwende die beiden Formen nebeneinander nur als Analogie. Außerdem habe ich noch eingefügt, dass »zum 31. Dezember geräumt« in der Quelle wörtlich so vorkommt, und dass ich darunter *bis zum* verstehe.

Comment: Ich verstehe immer weniger, warum Hubert meine inzwischen gelöschte Antwort nicht über den grünen Klee gelobt hat.

Answer (score -1):

1.Ist »Ich möchte zum 31. 10. ausziehen« korrektes Deutsch? Ja.

2.Was genau ist damit gemeint? Du möchtest genau an dem Tag ausziehen, nicht schon davor.

3.Gibt es regionale Unterschiede in der Beantwortung der Fragen 1 und 2? (Soweit ich weiß) nein.

Comment: Woher kommst du, sprachlich gesehen?

Comment: Ad 1: Kannst du das auch irgendwie belegen? Ad 2: Ich stimme dir zwar zu, Carsten S (in seiner Antwort) und Em1 (in einem Kommentar zu meiner Frage) behaupten aber das Gegenteil. Ad 3: Wenn von vier Personen (du, Em1, Carsten S und ich) zwei »a« und zwei »b« sagen, vermute ich doch regionale Unterschiede.

Comment: Das ist natürlich schon irgendwie strange, da stimme ich dir zu. Nein, ich kann das nicht belegen. Wenn man nach konkreten Regeln fragt, warum das so ist, wie ich es vermute, muss ich dieses mal leider passen, bei dieser sprachlichen Konstellation fällt mir auf Anhieb keine ein. Das ist mein subjektives Sprachgefühl, das mich in der Vergangenheit eher selten getäuscht hat.
@chirlu
Deutsch ist meine Muttersprache. Ich komme aus Hannover und spreche ich reines Hochdeutsch.