# Welche Präposition für eine Frist?

Tags: translation, preposition

Auf Englisch kann man sagen:

> You must complete the work *by* tomorrow.

Wie würde man diesen Satz auf Deutsch sagen? Welche deutsche Präposition entspricht *by* in diesem Zusammenhang?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary? What is still unclear?

Comment: @Alex.S Können Sie ein gutes Wörterbuch empfehlen, das nützlich sein würde?

I thought of using "bevor" but I was unsure if there was another word closer to the english meaning. That's all.

Comment: The "other word" would be "bis". We don't really like simple dictionary questions here. You should be investing at least a bit of your own effort before asking here. dict.cc or leo.org are nice dictionaries that would answer your single word questions without human intervention.

Comment: @tofro Sorry, I shall remember this in the future.

Comment: Verwandt: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25298/m%C3%B6chte-zum-31-10-ausziehen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Möglich sind *bis* und *zu*, wobei *zu* deutlich gehobener ist, aber dafür eindeutig (dagegen könnte *Ich brauche den Bericht bis morgen* auch verstanden werden als „von jetzt bis morgen, danach brauche ich ihn nicht mehr“). Üblicher ist es jedoch, ganz auf eine Präposition zu verzichten und die Zeitangabe mit *spätestens* zu verbinden:

> Die Arbeit ist spätestens morgen abzuschließen.

Comment: *Bis* und *spätestens* sind klar, aber wie würde eine Formulierung mit *zu* aussehen? Steh' gerade auf der Leitung...

Comment: @chirlu Ich habe verstanden, dass man "Du musst die Arbeit bis morgen machen" sagen könnte (Ich habe auch verstanden, dass _bis_ in diesem Satz  „nicht später als“ entspricht) Geht auch "Du musst  die Arbeit _zu_ morgen machen"?

Comment: @Stephie, genau wie _bis_ eigentlich: _Ich brauche den Bericht zu Montagmittag_, _Sie müssen zum 13. damit fertig sein_ usw.

Comment: @ra1inmaster: Ja, man würde aber in beiden Fällen lieber Perfekt benutzen, oder Zustandspassiv im Präsens: _Du mußt die Arbeit bis/zu morgen gemacht haben_ bzw. _Die Arbeit muß bis/zu morgen gemacht sein_. Deine Version ist aber auch nicht falsch.

Comment: @chirlu Danke für Ihre Hilfe!

Answer (score 2):

> Du musst die Arbeit bis morgen erledigen.

Chirlus Antwort nimmt den Adressaten aus der Antwort raus - ich meine hier kann man fast wörtlich übersetzen und dem Original so nahe kommen.